# How can I write setUp function without defining a TestCase class?

Tags: python, unit-testing, installation, pytest

I need to write a `unittest` setUp function to run before each test function. The problem is the test functions are not in a `TestCase` inherited class and I cannot put them inside a class because they used tons of fixtures that need lots of hand work to make them work.
Any suggestion about how to write setUp function outside of a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this doesn't answer the question, then I think the question needs a lot more detail and context:

```
def setUp():
  #...do setUp stuff

def test1():
  setUp()
  # ... do test 1 stuff

def test2():
  setUp()
  # ... do test 2 stuff
```

Comment: You're right man! my mind was full of very complex ways. simple is better than complex!